# What's the meaning of the expression「すごい！生きてる！」?

Tags: meaning

After a while of searching, I think this phrase might be used to express the feeling of being extremely amazed by something, to the point you're glad to be alive at this very moment or like you can feel the "weight" of your own life? Still, this is just my assumption and even I'm not sure myself (sounds kind of far-fetched tbh).

This is my first time asking a question here so I apologize for any mistakes!

Edit: For the context, the phrase was used by an actress (to be precise, an idol who just started her first acting gig and is quite clueless about acting) to compliment her co-star (a child actress in demand, has been acting for a long time) on her excellent acting and strong work ethic.
[image]

Comment: complete depends on the context of the utterance. you need to add details about the situation in which this was said, as the meaning could vary wildly depending on the context

Comment: @kandyman thank you for pointing out the lack of context in my question! it was said when an actress (actually an idol who just started her first acting gig, quite clueless about acting itself) complimented her co-star (a child actress in demand, has been acting for a long time) on the child's excellent acting and strong work ethic.

Comment: It's often best to share the context directly rather than try to interpret and translate it. Can you share something that will let people check the scene first-hand?

Comment: @Leebo i just added an image of the context to the question up there. Thank you and sorry for the inconvenience..!

Comment: It's not clear who she is saying is "alive". It could be the character the child actor plays.

Comment: @aguijonazo That was my impression:  that she was saying the acting was so amazing that the character seemed to really come alive.

Comment: @aguijonazo Thank you. That was actually my first assumption when reading the text (before searching for more on the Internet haha.....)

Comment: @A.Ellett Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I right that this is from the 6th chapter of 推しの子?

The meaning of "すごい、生きてる" is simply "Amazing, [someone/something] is alive!", and nothing more. There is no idiomatic meaning. Unfortunately, even with this much context, it's hard to tell who is being referred to as "alive".

- Is it referring to Kana Arima, like "**Kana-chan is** alive"? If Ai were Kana's fan who has only seen her on TV, she might say "(かなちゃんが)生きてる!" However, this is unlikely in this situation, since Ai is also a star and this comment came after Ai had worked with Kana for a while. Additionally, this doesn't naturally connect with the following statement about "how actors think about a lot of things".
- Is it referring to Ai herself, like "**I am** alive"? For example, one might say "(私は)生きてる" when you are happily enjoying a hobby or after you have recovered from a serious illness. However, since it's used together with すごい here, it seems more likely that it refers to someone else. And saying "I am alive" after inspired by the performance of a four-year-old child seems strange.
- Is it referring to the girl character played by Kana Arima, like "It seems like **◯◯ is** (almost) alive"? If the character played required special makeup or was a famous historical figure, this might be correct, but it doesn't seem to be the case in this situation.

In conclusion, the exclamation "(X is) Alive!" here looks very abrupt and odd to me, and it's unclear who it refers to. Given that this is a simulated oral interview and Ai isn't portrayed as a particularly logical character, it might be best not to overanalyze this.

Comment: Many many thanks for the helpful answer! The text comes from a recently released interview, but what Ai said there was indeed about that one movie she worked together with Kana in chapter 6. 

And yeah, while "すごい、生きてる" has a simple meaning, I had quite a hard time trying to connect its meaning with the context of the whole interview. I think it most likely refers to the character played by Kana, but even so the exclamation "生きてる" here still feels weird somehow.

Comment: @ayecye710 So it looks like your guess is as good as mine :) Questions from someone who already knows Japanese well like you can be extremely hard to answer without enough context, so next time [please read this](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2189/5010) and provide enough context.

Comment: Thank you again! To be honest my Japanese is still lacking a whole lot so I'm absolutely not confident when it comes to reading comprehension. And yes I will definitely provide enough context next time..!